# unrecognized expression selecting custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used below custom selector

```
$(div["data-sort-helper='+newId+'"]')
```

so that I can select this:  `<div data-sort-helper="5"></div>`

but I got

> `unrecognized expression: div["data-sort-helper=5"]` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string concatenation is not proper, you can wrap the attribute value if needed.

```
$('div[data-sort-helper="' + newId + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is wrong

```
$("div[data-sort-helper='"+newId+"']")
```